# Broken background-image pattern in other screen size

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have an obstacle when using the background-image pattern.
I am developing a website in 1366 x 768 screen size, and all of them look perfectly.
But when I check the screen with the size of 1280 x 800 and below, the background-image so truncated.
And cutting different for each monitor screen size,

This is the detail of cropped image:
[image]

How to handle this problem? Please help.
Thank you :)

Comment: How about if you will use linear gradient with opacity starting from some size with @media queries?

Answer (score 1):

detect the screen resolution by media query and add `background-size` by css.

for example

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .header{
      background-size: 153% auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay i already set using it. But very complicated to make it fit.
The dot just cropped 1-2px.
But the [numomma.com](http://www.numomma.com/) create perfectly.